# In SQL query with subquerys WHERE clause don't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 Tables - `DimWarehouses`, `DimProducts` and `DimTime`. And I make a set in SQL Query. Everything gonna be OK, but I need that result would be where Cost or Stock dont equals to 0. In My Query WHERE Clause don't work.

How to write Where Clause that it would work?

```
where bb.COST <>0 or bb.stock <> 0
```

Query:

```
    select 
    bb.TimeKey,
    bb.ProductKey,
    bb.WarehouseKey,
    bb.stock,
    bb.COST
    from(
    SELECT dt.timekey, 
           a.productkey, 
           b.warehousekey,
           Isnull((SELECT SUM(quantyti) 
                   FROM   aa f 
                   WHERE  a.productkey = f.productkey
                          AND b.warehousekey = f.warehousekey 
                          AND f.timekey <= dt.timekey), 0) AS stock, 
           Isnull((SELECT SUM(COST) 
                   FROM   aa f 
                   WHERE  a.productkey = f.productkey 
                          AND b.warehousekey = f.warehousekey 
                          AND f.timekey <= dt.timekey), 0) AS COST
FROM   dimproducts a, 
       (SELECT warehousekey FROM   dimwarehouses) b, 
       (SELECT 20121002 AS timekey ) dt         
     )bb
                where 
bb.COST <>0 or 
bb.stock <> 0
```

Table aa:

```
TimeKey ProductKey   WarehouseKey   Quantyti    Cost
20120901    1              1          10.000    100.00
20120901    1              1         -10.000    -100.00
20120901    2              1           5.000    50.00
20120901    2              1          15.000    150.00
20120901    2              2           3.000    30.00
20120901    3              1           0.000    20.00
20120901    3              2          10.000    0.00
```

Result:

```
TimeKey ProductKey  WarehouseKey    stock   COST
20121002    2                  1    20.000  200.00
20121002    3                  1    0.000   20.00
20121002    2                  2    3.000   30.00
20121002    3                  2    10.000  0.00
```

I need Result:

```
TimeKey ProductKey  WarehouseKey    stock   COST
20121002    2                  1    20.000  200.00
20121002    2                  2    3.000   30.00
```

Comment: do you need both condition to be true?

Comment: No I need one or another would be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end you should say

```
where 
bb.COST <>0 and bb.stock <> 0
```

instead of

```
where 
    bb.COST <>0 or bb.stock <> 0
```

if you want that result.

Comment: bb.COST <>0 or bb.stock <> 0 is true if at least one of them is true. In your case, for those two rows beside your needed result, at least one value is 0

Answer (score 0):

To get the result that you want you should use

```
where bb.COST <>0 AND bb.stock <> 0
```

Using OR it will return rows that have either of values different from 0 while you want both values different from 0.